# Where are Directory Utility's logs on OSX?

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx

I'm trying to debug an ActiveDirectory binding problem, but I can't seem to find the log files for Directory Utility.  Anyone know where they are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
/Library/Logs/DirectoryService/DirectoryService.error.log
/Library/Logs/DirectoryService.server.log
/var/log/system.log
/var/log/kdc.log
```

You can use Console or Server Admin to browse these.

Comment: I found what I was looking for in `/Library/Logs/DirectoryService/DirectoryService.debug.log`.  To turn on debug-level logging, first call `sudo killall -USR1 DirectoryService`.

Answer (score 0):

All of the logs for the system should be in /var/log

Comment: There are a lot of log files in there, but nothing about Directory Utility.